# Highcharts, Newtonsoft.Json and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vb.net, highcharts

I have my MS SQL data in json. I use Newtonsoft.Json for this.
My json I use this;

```
> Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, New
> Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting())
```

And my json look like this;

```
> {"Id":16846,"AXA":2.2090,"BXB":2.2270,"HMS":"08:17:05"},
{"Id":16847,"AXA":2.2091,"BXB":2.2271,"HMS":"08:17:21"},
{"Id":16848,"AXA":2.2087,"BXB":2.2271,"HMS":"08:18:02"},
{"Id":16852,"AXA":2.2090,"BXB":2.2270,"HMS":"08:42:00"},
```

In asp.net aspx page I want to categories: to be shows time as this;

> 08:17:05, 08:17:21, 08:18:02, 08:42:00 so on...

And I want my 2 series look like this;

```
>     series: [{
>               name: 'BUY',
>               data: [2.2090, 2.2091, 2.2087, 2.2090]
>                     }, {
>               name: 'SELL',
>               data: [2.2270, 2.2271, 2.2271, 2.2270]
>     }]
```

My question is how to put data into categories to show time and how to put data into two series. I am having difficult time to send my data into aspx part.

I find this code but I dont know how to apply my jason to be formated as I want it.

```
>     dLen = json.length,
>        ret = [];
>        for (var i = 0; i < dLen; i++) {
>         ret.push(parseInt(d[i].x, 10));}
```

I thank you for reading my post and I hope I can get some detail information so I can build my first asp.net highchart dynamically.

Kind Regards,

Thank you mason. I am not sure if I am correct but I created my Serialized as;

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Public Class SerializedJsonDT
    Private mstrLine As String

    '{"Id":16846,"AXA":2.2090,"BXB":2.2270,"HMS":"08:17:05"}
    'This was my json output. And I will change the output with
    'this Serialization prosses. Then I will pass this class to json.

    <DataContract> _
    Public Class [MyClass]

        'CURRENCY: BUY Data
        <DataMember> _
        Public Property WillSerializeKurBuy() As Decimal
            Get
                Return m_WillSerializeKurBuy
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                m_WillSerializeKurBuy = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_WillSerializeKurBuy As Decimal

        'CURRENCY: SELL Data
        <DataMember> _
        Public Property WillSerializeKurSell() As Decimal
            Get
                Return m_WillSerializeKurSell
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                m_WillSerializeKurSell = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_WillSerializeKurSell As Decimal

        'CURRENCY: TIME Categories
        <DataMember> _
        Public Property WillSerializeKurTarih() As String
            Get
                Return m_WillSerializeKurTarih
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_WillSerializeKurTarih = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_WillSerializeKurTarih As String

    End Class

End Class
```

Now as you mention I will create a function on server side but I dont know how to send dt (datatable) from function to this class. I thank you for your kind response and showing me a right direction. I guess I am doing step by step to achieve the goal. I hope you can show me or pointing me a more direction. I need more of your help. :)

Kind Regards,

Comment: How about create a server side class that, when serialized, would match the desired JSON output. Then create a function to go from `dt` to your new class. Then convert the new class to JSON and send it to the client side?

Comment: Thank you mason. I created my class as you stated. But how to use this class on my function. I didnt create any function yet. I post my class above. Can you tell me I am on right direction? I am doing step by step with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in C# because I'm not as familiar with VB.NET. But you can have the code automatically translated if you want.

```
public class MyJsonFriendlyClass()
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<int> data {get;set;}

    public MyJsonFriendlyClass()
    {
        data=new List<int>();
    }

    public static List<MyJsonFriendlyClass> GetJsonFriendlyClasses(DataTable dt)
    {
         List<MyJsonFriendlyClass> returndata=new List<MyJsonFriendlyClass>();
         MyJsonFriendlyClass buy=new MyJsonFriendlyClass();
         buy.name="BUY";
         MyJsonFriendlyClass sell=new MyJsonFriendlyClass();
         sell.name="SELL";
         foreach(DataRow dr in dt)
         {
             buy.data.Add(dr["AXA"]);//you may have to convert based on data type of your column
             sell.data.Add(dr["BXB"]);
         }
         returndata.Add(buy);
         returndata.Add(sell);
         return returndata;      
    }
}
```

Usage

```
List<MyJsonFriendlyClass> classes=GetJsonFriendlyClasses(dt);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classes);
```

What we're doing is creating a class that, when serialized to JSON, will match the data structure you want to end up with. Then we go from dt (I assume that's a DataTable) to a list of our new classes. We serialize the resulting list, and I assume from there you'll return it to the client for processing in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi mason, thank you again. Your I try to convert (online) C# to VB and it was some error on your code. List<MyJsonFriendlyClass(); didnt have closing >. I play it and find the > missing. I corrected an converted VB. I change my class and now I am using your class. Now on the usage I get only for [] json. I will re write your class and usage as vb.net and can you help me why I am getting only [].?

Comment: Sorry about the missing angled bracket, I've updated the answer with that. The reason you're getting an empty set returned is that I did not actually write the code that would convert from the DataTable to the List<MyJsonFriendlyClass> I thought you could handle that bit. It was unclear from your question just how you categorize each DataRow into the BUY and SELL categories.

Comment: Sorry mason, I type to quick before reading your answer. BUY was AXA, and Sell was BXB. Categories is will be HMS. I couldn't handle a bit because I am very new to serialize to json. I thought it will be easy to use highchart but wasn't. Need great work and help. I thank you all your kind response. I will check it tonight the code again.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on that information.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding and your patience. I am getting error on this 2 lines of code. I cant convert them to vb. MyJsonFriendlyClass buy=new MyJsonFriendlyClass() {name: "BUY"};

Comment: I used an object initializer. The code converter you're using probably doesn't know how to convert those to VB.NET. I'll edit my answer so that it's more likely to convert properly.

Comment: Thank you mason. With your patient and help I have over come of the conversion of VB. And I understand bit more about serialization of json. I coded but below this post I have my code on default.aspx which I will later want to use Highchart in it. And I have default.aspx.vb code which gets data from MSSQL and serialized json with your help. End of it I have SerializedJsonDT Class. In SerializedJsonDT class I make someting stupid and my json look awful. Again I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json in that way

```
var categories = [],
    series = [
        {
            name: "BUY",
            data: []
        },{
            name: "SELL",
            data: []
        }
    ];

var json = [{
    "Id": 16846,
    "AXA": 2.2090,
    "BXB": 2.2270,
    "HMS": "08:17:05"
}, {
    "Id": 16847,
    "AXA": 2.2091,
    "BXB": 2.2271,
    "HMS": "08:17:21"
}, {
    "Id": 16848,
    "AXA": 2.2087,
    "BXB": 2.2271,
    "HMS": "08:18:02"
}, {
    "Id": 16852,
    "AXA": 2.2090,
    "BXB": 2.2270,
    "HMS": "08:42:00"
}];

$.each(json, function (i, p){
    series[0].data.push(p.AXA);
    series[0].data.push(p.BXB);
    categories.push(p.HMS);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RJ9Bq/

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you for your post, I try it, but didnt work.